# Rules around custom policy's "PolicyId" name

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am building several custom policies and I need to come up with a meaningful naming convention for the pack of files relates to a specific group of files come with Starter Packs

What are the rules and repercussions around PolicyId I need to define on top of each policy xml file (shown in the snippet below)

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
  TenantId="yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_PasswordReset"
  PublicPolicyUri="http://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_PasswordReset">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never come across any issue in terms of names.

If you don't add "B2C_1A_" to the name, it is added when you upload it.

I leave the base and extension files alone.

Then I have my own extension policy file where I add custom code (maybe overriding methods) and also have policy files for common themes e.g. API, federation, MFA etc. The name reflects the function.

The maximum depth for inheritance is 10 policy files.

Comment: Thank you for help. You said "I leave the base and extension files alone." Does it mean you leave the names as "TrustFrameworkLocalization", "TrustFrameworkExtensions" and rustFrameworkBase?

Comment: Leave the names as is. Also don't make changes to the files (other than the keys). That way it's easy to update them when the starter pack is updated.

Comment: I have multiple custom policies to upload, the have different TrustFrameworkBase. The relying parties in variations of starter pack need their own  TrustFrameworkBase. How would you handle such situation?

Comment: I then have TrustFrameworkBaseLocal, TrustFrameworkBaseMFA etc., for the different starter packs. I always try and use MFA because many of the samples are based on that. I always use another extension custom policy e.g. ExtensionUseCase1, ExtensionUseCase2 etc., that inherits from "TrustFrameworkExtensions", and here I override the Base policy as required. Then the RP is also called XXXUseCase1 etc., so you can see at a glance what starter pack they derive from and what use case they perform.

Comment: For Azure Pipelines, I use 1_TrustFrameworkBaseLocal, 2_TrustFrameworkExtensions etc. so that the script knows what order to upload the files.